# Split string into single strings of length 1: How to avoid empty string?

Tags: string, kotlin

```
val segm = str.split("")
        // .filter { it -> it.length > 0 }
println(segm)
```

With "Testing 1234" as "str" I get "[, T, e, s, t, i, n, g,  , 1, 2, 3, 4, ]"

With the additional filter it works. But nevertheless: **How do I have to use String.split() in a way, that I avoid empty strings in the result-array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a built-in API that ignores empty splits, and frankly, I don't see what's wrong with using a `filter`.

If you don't like the fact that `filter` loops over the splits unnecessarily, you can [`splitToSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split-to-sequence.html), which produces a lazy sequence.

```
str.splitToSequence("").filter(String::isNotEmpty).toList()
```

Alternatively, just remove the first and last splits - those are the only ones that will be empty.

```
str.split("").run { subList(1, lastIndex) }
// note that subList produces a "view" of the original list
// it does not create a copy
```

If you really want to only use `split`, you can use the overload that takes a `Regex` and use a regex that matches all zero-width positions in the string, except the start and end.

```
// this matches any position where there is no start of string (^) before it, and no end of string ($) after it
str.split("(?<!^)(?!$)".toRegex())
```

This is probably going to be a lot slower than the other approaches, since matching against regex is complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Frame challenge: what you're doing is splitting the string into individual *characters* — and there are several existing methods which can do that to a string, such as:

- [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/as-sequence.html) gives a `Sequence` of characters.
- [`asIterable()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/as-iterable.html) gives an `Iterable` of characters. (You can do most things to an Iterable that you can to a List.)
- [`toCharArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-char-array.html) gives a `CharArray`. (Though iterables are generally preferred in Kotlin as they're more flexible and better-supported.)
- [`forEach()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/for-each.html) performs a given action on each character. (This means you can do e.g. `for (c in myString) { … }`.)

Using one of these will be simpler than `split`ting, and probably more efficient; it'll also make the intent of the code easier to anyone reading it.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.split("").filterNot { it.isBlank() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with space and join the string and then you can push the resulted string into array.It will work just fine.

```
val str = "Testing 1234";
val segm = str.split(" ").join("")
        
println(segm);
println(segm.length)
```